# How can I make this git command alias?

Tags: git, bash, alias

I want to make a alias, like this below

`gc this is a test message` convert to `git commit -m "this is a test message"`.

How can I do this? I want that in my bashrc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This isn't an alias, but try

```
function gc() {
  git commit -m "$*"
}
```

Answer (score 13):

I have these alias in my .bashrc:

```
alias ga='git add'
alias gp='git push'
alias gl='git log'
alias gs='git status'
alias gd='git diff'
alias gdc='git diff --cached'
alias gm='git commit -m'
alias gma='git commit -am'
alias gb='git branch'
alias gc='git checkout'
alias gra='git remote add'
alias grr='git remote rm'
alias gpu='git pull'
alias gcl='git clone'
```

I normally commit with `gm "msg"`

Comment: Nice, thanks for sharing these.  I like getting git status on current dir when there are other folders above CWD I'm not working w/in the project , so added this: `alias gs='git status .' ` .. and then since it's my #1 git cmd, this is even faster `alias g=gs`

Answer (score 11):

bash `alias` definitions don't take parameters.

Try using a bash function in your .bashrc:

```
function gc () { 
    git commit -m "$*" 
}
```

Comment: I like and tried this, but not working in my bash env.  Do you know why I am getting this error message ? : **error: path spec '*<commit string i tried to enter>*' did not match any file(s) known to git.**  .. I run it like this *$ gc test commit message here* .. and I also tried to make an alias to the function

Comment: My guess is that somehow the resulting invocation has a closing quote before you intended.  You might try adding a line `echo "git commit -m "$*"` before the actual line in the function to see what is being generated.

Comment: Thanks for getting back.  I tried it with the echo and then I saw it working .. I must have missed something before, but it works now.  Fyi, with your echo, I think you missed one quote and I wasn't sure about them being nested; so I did it like this : `echo  "git commit -m \"$*\" "`

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
alias ci = "!f() { git commit -m \"$*\"; }; f"
```

Unfortunately gc is already a subcommand and can't be aliased.